# Terms needed to approximate with given error?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, approximation

How many terms of this series would one need to add to get an approximation of $\pi$ with error less than $10^{-4}$?

$$ 4 - \frac{4}{3} + \frac{4}{5} - \frac{4}{7} + \cdots $$

So far, I wrote the series as $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n  \frac{4}{2n+1}$$

and will use $|S-S_n|< a_n + 1$ , but am not sure how to go about doing so from here.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Approximating_sums

Comment: Roughly $40,000$  since it's an alternating series. *Machin*'s formula: $\pi =16\arctan\frac15-4\arctan\frac 1{239}$ requires only $4$ terms.

Comment: Where you wrote $a_n+1$, might you have intended $a_{n+1}$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Bernard: You're wrong.  It only takes about $20,000$.  See my answer below. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael Hardy: It was a rough computation, as I said, only based on the fact it's an alternating series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle S_n = 4\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$.

Then

$$
|S_{10001}-S_{10000}| = |a_{10001}| = \left|\frac{-4}{20003}\right| < 0.0002.\tag 1
$$
We know that $S_{10000}>\pi>S_{10001}$ but $\pi$ is somewhat closer to the latter term than to the former, and $S_{10002}>\pi>S_{10001}$ and $\pi$ is somewhat closer to the former term than to the latter.  Make this an exercise: $|S_n-\pi|$ decreases as $n$ grows; that justifies my former two statements.

Thus $\pi$ is half-way between $S_{10001}$ and some number that is between $S_{10000}$ and $S_{10002}$.  So $|\pi-S_{10002}|$ is **less than half** the difference between $S_{10000}$ and $S_{10001}$, and that difference is given in $(1)$.

The error is about **half** the size of the next term.

Comment: Minor(?) math typo:  $a_{10001}=-4/20003$, not $-4/20000$.  (Also, it's the *even* partial sums that are larger than $\pi$, not the odd ones.)

Comment: sigh..... Haste makes waste.....

Comment: ok, I hope I've fixed these details$\ldots\ldots$ ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You might want to throw absolute value signs around things in (1), since otherwise you could also say $-4/20003\lt0.0000000000002$.... (Actually, don't you really want to work with $S_{10000}-S_{9999}$?)

Comment: As I said, haste makes waste$\ldots\ldots$ ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I wrote an earlier version of this with $9999$ as the smallest index considered and then revised it, but maybe that was hasty too.

Answer (score 3):

The [alternating series theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Approximating_sums) says that the error is less than the absolute value of the first neglected term, so you just need to find the first term less than $10^{-4}$.  You don't know that this term is the first one for which the error is less than $10^{-4}$, but you know it works.

Comment: That is certainly _not_ the first one for which the error is less than $10^{-4}$.  The alternating series theorem says that many terms are sufficient, not that that many are necessary, and there's a rather simple reason why so many are not necessary in this instance. ${}\qquad{}$